# why don't my sha1s match, if I compute them inside a bash function?

Tags: bash, awk, tdd

**(I'm struggling to find a good, descriptive title for this question, that would help future searchers.  Suggestions/edits are welcome.)**

I am adding a simple TDD framework (implemented in bash) to one of my C++ projects.  Most of my tests can simply pass/fail based on exit() return value, but some tests have complex output that is best dealt with by computing a hash & comparing against a golden value.

Also, some of those more complex tests (compiled from C++) are written to have different output behavior when certain environment variables are defined.  So, I expect the golden values to be different, depending on those envvars.

To generate my golden values, I exploit bash's `&>` facility to capture both stdout and stderr, for piping into `sha1sum`:

```
echo `RV_TRACE="fib" $RV_TESTDIR/$RV_TESTNAME &> >(sha1sum)`
```

The output of the above command ends with a `-`, which my OCD just couldn't abide.  So I added a call to `awk` to trim it off:

```
echo `RV_TRACE="fib" $RV_TESTDIR/$RV_TESTNAME &> >(sha1sum) | awk '{print $1;}'`
```

Preliminary testing showed that both of the above yielded the same numerical results, as expected:

```
038735b655da0162b0d3911ae0ca7bd7230673c1 -
038735b655da0162b0d3911ae0ca7bd7230673c1
```

So far, so good.  But I actually wanted this sha1 generation to be done inside a bash function, which I wrote like this:

```
rv_trace_test() {
  echo +++ $@ $RV_TESTDIR/$RV_TESTNAME
  echo `$@ $RV_TESTDIR/$RV_TESTNAME &> >(sha1sum)`
  echo `$@ $RV_TESTDIR/$RV_TESTNAME &> >(sha1sum) | awk '{print $1;}'`
}
```

and called like this:

```
rv_trace_test RV_TRACE=\"fib\"
```

But now the two sha1 computations no longer agree, numerically.

```
+++ RV_TRACE="fib" /home/ryan/src/rv/test/004.001.trace-enabled
b23ce3531305e291ae2d3d2401dbeb93effe9ce6 -
cfd355f46f019acfa451ed1c9044f51d9a589a52
```

... And I cannot, for the life of me, figure out why.   I've tried replacing the `$@` with `$*`, but it didn't seem to make any difference.  It also doesn't seem to matter if the envvar that I pass in has quotes or not, or if I escape them or not.   It doesn't even have to be an envvar that my compiled test is even aware of.  Any envvar at all will cause the mismatch, in the function version.

What is causing this?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using process substitution instead of just piping, i.e. why are you using `&> >(sha1sum)` instead of `2>&1 | sha1sum`

Comment: Have you considered looking at what you're hashing? You'll find you're hashing an error message.

Comment: Variable assignments are not executed after expanding variables. And quotes aren't processed, either.

Comment: @Barmar (1) because I just learned about the former, and thought it was equivalent to the latter.  (2) how should I apply your second comment in the context of solving my problem?

Comment: @Barmar suddenly, I understand your second comment-- and I think that's the answer!

Comment: @thatotherguy In the case of the function'd implementation, you turned out to be right: I was hashing an error message.   Barmar's answer explains why.

Comment: Keep in mind, though, that `&>` doesn't really provide any guarantees about how stdout and stderr will be merged into one stream. One run might produce `stdout1 stderr1 stdout2`, the next `stdout1 stdout2 stderr1`.

Comment: @chepner My test is single-threaded, and I call fflush(stdout) before every stderr output, and fflush(stderr) afterwards.    But your advice is otherwise worthy of people's attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable assignments and quotes aren't processed after expanding variables. So when you do:

```
echo `$@ $RV_TESTDIR/$RV_TESTNAME &> >(sha1sum)`
```

it will treat `RV_TRACE="fib"` as a command to execute, not an environment variable to assign.

One solution is to set the environment variable when you're calling the function, instead of inside the function:

```
RV_TRACE=fib rv_trace_test
```

and then take `$@` out of the function.

Another way is to use `eval` inside the function.

```
rv_trace_test() {
  echo +++ $@ $RV_TESTDIR/$RV_TESTNAME
  eval "$@ $RV_TESTDIR/$RV_TESTNAME &> >(sha1sum)"
  eval "$@ $RV_TESTDIR/$RV_TESTNAME &> >(sha1sum) | awk '{print \$1;}'"
}
```

BTW,

```
echo `command`
```

is mostly equivalent to just

```
command
```

Comment: That's exactly it!  Thanks.